# MYSQL 5.6 install error from missing dependency libaio

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, installation, dependencies

So I uninstalled mysql 5.1 and then downloaded the client, devel and server rpm's for mysql 5.6

I did a `rpm -ivh` of each rpm but got this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
libaio.so.1()(64bits) is needed by MYSQL-server-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64
libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bits) is needed by MYSQL-server-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64
libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bits) is needed by MYSQL-server-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64
```

I looked around but it does not seem this error is well documented. Do I need to install a dependency? If so which one and how?

My OS is CentOS Linux 6.2 on x86_64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# yum install libaio.x86_64 libaio-devel.x86_64
```

and try again.

But wait, why not install `mysql-server` via yum?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

The reason I didn't use `mysql-server` is because it only installs the earliest stable release. I am trying to install MYSQL 5.6.

Comment: As of this writing, default mysql server version is 5.1.73.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let yum install dependencies?

```
yum -y install http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-shared-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm
yum -y install http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-server-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm
yum -y install http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-client-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm
```

Note: My previous post was deleted. I revised my answer and hope the moderators will see the **DIFFERENCE** now.